# objectinputstream.readobject() line: not available [local variables unavailable]

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, objectinputstream

I have written a client that reads TCP messages using an `ObjectInputStream` in a separate thread from the main thread. I am using Eclipse and although no exception is thrown in the console, at random times the debug window will open and show the following error in what I assume is the Thread stack trace:

```
Thread[Thread-5](Suspended (exception ThreadDeath))
  objectinputstream.readobject() line: not available [local variables unavailable]
  ReceiveRunnable.run()line:25
  Thread.run()line:not available
```

This the  code that the exception points to:

```
class ReceiveRunnable implements Runnable {
  Object receivedObject;

  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      try {             
        receivedObject = client.objectInStream.readObject();  //line 25
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // client.reconnectToServer();

        // System.out.println("IO exception in run()");
    // System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Class Not Found exception in run()");
        System.out.println(e);
    e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception in ReceiveRunnable.run()");
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`client.objectInStream` is created in the `Client` class:

```
void connectToServer(){
    try {
        connected = false;

        socket = new Socket(host, port);

        System.out.println("<Connected> " + socket);

        objectInStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        objectOutStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        receiveThread = new Thread(new ReceiveRunnable(this, "receive"));

        receiveThread.start();

        /* used to periodically ping the server*/
        long delay = 0;
        long period = 5000;

        connTimer.schedule(clientCheckConnTimerTask, delay, period);

        connected = true;

        sendString("[conn]" + clientUUID);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        msgBox.set2LineOkMessage("Can not connect to server.", "");
        msgBox.show();
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is causing the problem and how I might resolve please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that `try` isn't followed by a `catch (EOFException exc)` that closes the socket and breaks out of the loop, your code is incorrect.

You should always create the `ObjectOutputStream` before the `ObjectInputStream` for the same socket, not afterwards, otherwise you can get deadlocks.

Comment: I have added the exceptions that I am catching to my example (sorry for the indenting, it is not parsing correctly for some reason). `EOFException` is caught by `IOException`. Also I have swapped the order I am creating `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream`, although I don't think this is the cause of the problem it has speeded up the loading time, thanks.

Comment: I have left my application running for a few hours and your solution seems to have solved my problem. I don't understand why the order of creating the object streams should matter. Can you explain why it does?

Comment: See the Javadoc. The constructor of `ObjectOutputStream` writes a header that is read by the constructor of `ObjectInputStream`. If you create the input streams first on both ends, there is nothing to read so both sides deadlock. If either side creates the output stream first it doesn't happen. If both sides create the output stream first it can't happen regardless of what the other side does.